# Heroes of Newerth lagging periodically

Tags: unity, games

Everything was fine on Ubuntu 12.04. Today when I moved to Ubuntu 14.04 and installed HoN everything was fine, game loaded game started normally, in the game everything working fine just I have lags periodically(every 1-2 min). This lag is not long about couple of seconds.But when I have lags in team fights that make me lose a game! However I made contact with S2games(support for HoN) and they are not sure what make this lags.
So please help me.

I have laptop ASUS K50IN (all performances in game are on low) and I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 Unity.

Comment: What graphics do you have? You probably need a driver.

Comment: Nvidia geforce g102M and im using Nvidia driver 331.38

Comment: Are you sure you are using that driver? Sometimes upgrading removes them or you might need to use a different one now.

Comment: i tried all of them and all working fine just not for HoN...

Comment: Have you tried a different desktop environment other than unity? Just trying to rule possibilities out.

Comment: yes i did ... and its not working . i tried ubuntu ,mint,debian all environments and its the same... Only on slackware 14.1 is working fine.

Comment: I meant *[desktop environments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_environment)*, not Linux distributions.

Comment: like i said i did and i just mention that is not working in similar distros and theirs environments .

Comment: "all environments" includes which ones? Did you try LXDE and XFCE?

Comment: on ubuntu unity,kde,xfce,lxde on mint everything what u can download from official site same with debian... i really dont know what is not clean in my answer .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem that I have also been experiencing in DOTA 2. To solve it you need to upgrade your kernel manually. I upgraded to 3.14.4 personally.

Here is a guide on upgrading the kernel manually: 
[How to update kernel to the latest mainline version without any Distro-upgrade?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119080/how-to-update-kernel-to-the-latest-mainline-version-without-any-distro-upgrade)

I hope it will work for you !