# Lag spikes when playing games since upgrade to 14.04 from 12.04

Tags: 12.04, networking, games, 14.04, ping

I sometimes play games (Awesomenauts, CS:GO,...) on my Ubuntu 14.04 laptop. After upgrading from 12.04 to 14.04 last week the gameplay of all of my internet games suffers from lags every view minutes. The lags seem to apply only to my upstream (10:1 MBit [Down:Up]) since I can see other players move without lag but my character is stuck or moved back to previous position. The ping increases up to 500ms. The CPU runs smoothly without spikes.

- Any idea what the problem might be?
- Any hint on how I can find out if there is a software in 14.04 jamming my upstream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem that I have also been experiencing in DOTA 2. To solve it you need to upgrade your kernel manually. I upgraded to 3.14.4 personally.

Here is a guide on upgrading the kernel manually: [How to update kernel to the latest mainline version without any Distro-upgrade?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119080/how-to-update-kernel-to-the-latest-mainline-version-without-any-distro-upgrade)

I hope it will work for you !

PS : Sorry, my answer is duplicated here too [Heroes of Newerth lagging periodically](https://askubuntu.com/questions/449278/heroes-of-newerth-lagging-periodically) but both problems come from the same issue